# Do I need to revoke access tokens from Apple while using Sign-In with Apple if I never requested them?

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, oauth

So in our iOS app we have Apple Sing-In enabled. We get identity token from Apple which we then use to register user in our app but we never make request for access token.
New Apple rules require apps to have user account deletion and if you use Apple Sign-In you also need to revoke any tokens from Apple you have. But if we never requested access tokens from Apple should we do that(by first completing oauth flow and storing access token and refresh token just for later deletion)?

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12m75xbj

Answer (score 0):

we have the application with same situation that you describe and we solve this situation with calling REST API's of Apple and getting access and refresh token and complete the auth_code flow and store the refresh_token as the [forum's said](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708415). When user want to close their account in our app, we call Apple's revoke token API with these refresh_tokens we have.